# Struggling with slice syntax to join list element of a part of a list

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have a simple Python list like this:

```
>>> l=['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```

Now suppose I want to combine `l[2:6]` to a single element like this:

```
>>> l
['0', '1', '2345', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```

I am able to do it in steps into a new list, like this:

```
>>> l2=l[0:2]
>>> l2.append(''.join(l[2:6]))
>>> l2.extend(l[6:])
>>> l2
['0', '1', '2345', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```

Is there a way (that I am missing) to do this more simply and in place on the original list `l`?

**Edit**

As usual, [Sven Marnach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9605845/298607) had the perfect instant answer:

```
l[2:6] = ["".join(l[2:6])]
```

I had tried:

```
l[2:6] = "".join(l[2:6])
```

But without the braces, the string produced by the join was then treated as an iterable placing each character back in the list and reversing the join!

Consider:

```
>>> l=['abc','def','ghk','lmn','opq']
>>> l[1:3]=[''.join(l[1:3])] 
>>> l
['abc', 'defghk', 'lmn', 'opq']   #correct

>>> l=['abc','def','ghk','lmn','opq']
>>> l[1:3]=''.join(l[1:3])
>>> l
['abc', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'k', 'lmn', 'opq']   #not correct
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a slice assignment:

```
l[2:6] = ["".join(l[2:6])]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yep, pretty simple:

```
l[2:6] = [''.join(l[2:6])]
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to note the difference between a slice assignment:

```
>>> a = range(3)
>>> a
[0, 1, 2]
>>> a[1:3] = [4, 5, 6]
>>> a
[0, 4, 5, 6]
```

And an [EXTENDED](http://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/whatsnew/section-slices.html) slice assignment:

```
>>> a=range(6)
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> a[::2]
[0, 2, 4]
>>> a[::2]=[-1,-2,-3]
>>> a
[-1, 1, -2, 3, -3, 5]
>>> a[::2]=[-1,-2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: attempt to assign sequence of size 2 to extended slice of size 3
```

If the LH is an extended slice, the RH needs to be a sequence of the same length. A regular slice assignment can change the length of the list on the LH.